# are there any ways to send viber branded/buisness messages without partners api?

Tags: java, python, viber, viber-api, viber-bot-python

does viber api allows you any way to send branded messages throw your application and get answers without partners mentioned on this page https://info.viber.com/Viber-Business-Messages-Partners.html ? Or maybe is it possible to make your bot administrator of community and send notifycations such way? I made bot but it could only respond on users requests also got viber buisness acc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Viber bot already - then you are able to send messages when you need to notify them, not only during processing incoming request.

Everything you need is to remember `chat_id` somewhere (file or DB), initialize bot entity at desired moment (as you do that during request handling) and call `send_message` (with `chat_id` and `message` that you want to send.